# Find and replace a value in a file using tcl

Tags: split, tcl

I need to update the date in a file. Therefore, I am searching for the line with the day (`#define __VERSION_DAY 23`) and desperately trying to update it.

```
while {([gets $fp_Vers line] >= 0)} {

   if { [string match -nocase "#define*__VERSION_DAY*" $line] } {
      # Get the current day
      set day [clock format $systemTime -format {%d}]
      set line [split $line]
      # Replace the old value 
      set line [lreplace $line 2 $day]
      puts $fp_Vers $line
   }
}
```

It puts the following at the end of the file `{#define} __VERSION_DAY`. I don't understand ...
1) why there are brackets around define
2) why the value of the current day (i.e. 16) is missing.

Thanks for your contribution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily figure out what is going wrong by running the commands in a Tcl shell like `tkcon`. Doing this is strongly recommended to avoid running away and doing things that make no sense. In the following, commands (lines beginning with `%` are mixed with results.

```
% set line {#define __VERSION_DAY 23}
#define __VERSION_DAY 23
set day 16
16
% set line [split $line]
{#define} __VERSION_DAY 23
```

When splitting a string into a list, the string representation changes to make it possible to regenerate the list later, hence the braces around `#define` (which would otherwise be an invalid list item).

```
set line [lreplace $line 2 $day]
{#define} __VERSION_DAY
```

The `lreplace` command takes the following arguments: `list` `first` (index) `last` (index) `?element ...?` (zero or more elements to replace the range with). The contents of `day` (16) is interpreted as the last index in a range that you want to replace with nothing.

Try this instead:

```
% set line [join [lreplace [split $line] 2 2 $day]]
#define __VERSION_DAY 16
```

Regarding updating a date field in a file, your best bet is probably to do it somewhat like this:

```
set day 16
set f [open $filename]
set lines [split [string trim [read $f]] \n]
close $f

set result {}
set tag {#define __VERSION_DAY }
set pattern [string map {{ } *} $tag]
foreach line $lines {
    if {[string match -nocase $pattern $line]} {
        lappend result $tag$day
    } else {
        lappend result $line
    }
}

set f [open $filename2 w]
puts -nonewline $f [join $result \n]
close $f
```

**Note:** do not output `$result` directly, since the contents of the variable are quoted to preserve the list structure created by list-appending lines into it. By joining the lines using newline characters, the structure is changed to flat text, which works in output.

Or, using `fileutil` from the Tcllib,

```
package require fileutil

set day 16
set tag {#define __VERSION_DAY }
set pattern [string map {{ } *} $tag]
set f [open $filename2 w]
::fileutil::foreachLine line $filename {
    if {[string match -nocase $pattern $line]} {
        puts $f $tag$day
    } else {
        puts $f $line
    }
}
close $f
```

Note that the strategies are basically equivalent. The first solution uses list-appending lines into into a variable and later printing the joined-up text in it. The second solution instead prints each line directly. There is nothing to stop you from using the lowlevel `open`-`read`-`close` solution with direct printing or the `fileutil` solution with lines list-appended into a variable.

Documentation:
[close](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/close.htm),
[fileutil (package)](http://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/fileutil/fileutil.html),
[foreach](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/foreach.htm),
[if](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/if.htm),
[join](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/join.htm),
[lappend](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lappend.htm),
[lreplace](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lreplace.htm),
[open](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/open.htm),
[package](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/package.htm),
[puts](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/puts.htm),
[read](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/read.htm),
[set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm),
[split](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/split.htm),
[string](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/string.htm)

Comment: Tcl's list quoting _also_ guarantees that the result is a valid script that invokes the single command named in the first word passing in the other words as arguments, with _no_ unexpected substitutions (and that the minimum number of backslashes and braces are used in the serialization). The `#` at the beginning would violate that constraint if left unquoted.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answers, Peter and Donal!

Comment: I tried the first proposal from Peter `... foreach line $lines {
    if {[string match -nocase $pattern $line]} { ...` The `day` is updated and at the correct location ... but each line is put inside brackets `{ ... }`. And the ten lines end up in a single long line.

Comment: I just tried to write the lines directly back to the line and it works!    `set fp_Vers [open version.h r+]   

set lines [split [string trim [read $fp_Vers]] \n]   

close $fp_Vers  
set fp_Vers [open version.h w]  

set day [clock format $systemTime -format {%d}]  
set tag {#define __VERSION_DAY }  
set pattern [string map {{ } *} $tag]  
  
foreach line $lines {  
   if {[string match -nocase $pattern $line]} {  
       puts $fp_Vers $tag$day  
   } else {  
       puts $fp_Vers $line  
   }  
}`   But why are the quotations, that I tried to get rid of, gone now?

Comment: @Stingray: Are you sure you used the exact code I provided? If you for instance use `puts $f $result` instead of `puts -nonewline $f [join $result \n]`, you would get that kind of output. But, whatever works. Using `puts` as in my second suggestion and your own solution is just as good as using `lappend` as in my first suggestion.

Comment: @Peter: I used `puts $fp_Vers $result`. Thank you very much for supporting, your answer worked with that small change!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the `split` is adding in quotation that you don't expect, because it is satisfying other rules for Tcl list serializations that make sense on other situations. In this case, the easiest fix is to switch to using `regsub` to perform the replacement. Regular expressions are definitely sharp tools, but they're also sometimes totally the right approach anyway.

```
# Factor a few bits out for convenience

# The RE pattern we're looking for.
set VERSION_RE {(#define\s+_VERSION_DAY\s*).+}

# Get the current day as a replacement pattern
set dayReplacement [clock format $systemTime -format {\1%d}]

while {[gets $fp_Vers line] >= 0} {
    if {[regsub $VERSION_RE $line $dayReplacement line]} {
        # If we did the replacement, write the new value out
        puts $fp_Vers $line
    }
}
```

I suspect you might need to do a `seek` or `chan truncate` to reset where you are writing to, but that's your problem.

---

This works because when `regsub` is used with a variable-to-write-to argument, its Tcl result is the number of replacements performed. Without the `-all` switch, that's effectively a boolean: was the pattern found (and replaced) or not?

Comment: Maybe the Quartus 14.0 shell that I use for tcl does not support some commands or acts different. I couldn't find the version for it, but Quartus 11.1 already supported 8.5 (Tcl/Tk version 8.5, supplied by the Tcl DeveloperXchange)
I get the following output:

`% # The RE pattern we're looking for.
% set VERSION_RE {( #define\s+_VERSION_DAY\s* ).+}
% puts $VERSION_RE

**( #define\s+_VERSION_DAY\s* ).+** `

Comment: @Stingray: you've added blanks inside the parenthesis that shouldn't be there.

Comment: @Peter: Thanks for the hint. In the tcl script I don't have them. `set VERSION_RE {(#define\s+_VERSION_DAY\s*).+}` I suppose, they appeared, while editing the message here.